# stow: No packages to stow or unstow

Tags: stow

The following command works:

```
% pwd
/home/ismail/.dotfiles/.common-dotfiles
% stow --target=/home/ismail/.dotfiles/test .
```

But the following command does not work:

```
stow --target=/home/ismail/.dotfiles/test --dir=/home/ismail/.dotfiles/.common-dotfiles
```

It gives error:

```
stow: No packages to stow or unstow
```

How can I give the link of source in stow (instead of using .)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When stowing, you still need to specify what to stow or unstow.  With the `--dir` and `--target` options, all you're doing is to tell `stow` where packages are to be found and where they are to be linked to, but you don't tell it what to do.

In your case, either of these would work:

```bash
stow --target="$HOME/.dotfiles/test" --dir="$HOME/.dotfiles/.common-dotfiles" .
```

```bash
stow --target="$HOME/.dotfiles/test" --dir="$HOME/.dotfiles" .common-dotfiles
```

(I would personally prefer the second option as it refers to `.common-dotfiles` as the package to stow from `"$HOME/.dotfiles"`, while the first variation refers to `"$HOME/.dotfiles/.common-dotfiles"` as the directory containing packages.)

You can also explicitly tell `stow` that you want to stow a particular package with `--stow` (or `-S`):

```bash
stow --target="$HOME/.dotfiles/test" --dir="$HOME/.dotfiles" --stow .common-dotfiles
```